# How to view error logs in folder

Tags: tibco

I got requirement regarding without opening tibco designer,tibco admin gui how to view error logs in a folder or any file it will be logged.Is there any way to view error logs in a folder or any file.If it is possible kindly let me know how to configure to view the logs

Answer (score 1):

All Tibco logs are placed on the respective folders. While working on Designer there is a folder on your computer. When deployed to the server, the same situation, there is a folder there.
All logs are human readable. Tibco uses a wrapper on Log4J to log to file.
Please see the documentation for "Designer" and the server side application for location of this logs.
You are also able to redirect all this logs to a centralized server to be able to see them from there.
I wrote a costume palette to write this logs into elastic search so it is doable. You will have to read the documentation and API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer